# Como rodar PHP + Firebird no Docker?

Tags: php, firebird, docker, osx

Estou tentando rodar/criar um container no docker com PHP + Firebird, encontrei um container que roda o [Firebird](https://github.com/almeida/docker-php-firebird), encontrei outro que roda o PHP e o Firebird, porém quando tento consumir o banco de dados:

```
$conn  = ibase_connect('localhost:/database.fdb', 'user', 'masterkey');
```

recebo a mensagem:

```
Warning: ibase_connect(): Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". Failed to establish a connection
```

Eu estou trabalhando em um projeto que atualmente roda Firebird e precisamos migrar para PHP/MySQL e como é um banco muito grande precisamos acessar constantemente para migrar os dados. Já fiz alguns testes no Windows utilizando o IBExpert, o banco está funcionando corretamente.

Alguém já passou por esse problema, ou já tentou utilizar PHP + Firebird no Docker?

**RESOLVIDO**

Estava faltando a propriedade `links` para que o outro container pudesse conectar ao banco. Vou deixar o `docker-compose.yml` aqui caso alguém precise conectar com Firebird + PHP usando Docker.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: jacobalberty/firebird:2.5-ss
    ports:
      - 3050:3050
    volumes:
      - ./data:/databases
  php:
    image: almeida/php-firebird
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./www:/usr/share/nginx/html/
    links:
      - db
```

A senha para acessar o firebird dentro do container db está dentro do arquivo `/firebird/etc/SYSDBA.password`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu ainda não tenho acesso aos comentários, então vou responder diretamente aqui.

Não sei como você criou o container, se juntou o firebird e o php no mesmo container (o que não é recomendado) ou se colocou os dois em containers separados.

Se você criou os dois separadamente é necessário linkar os dois containers para que haja comunicação, só com o localhost não funciona, esse [artigo](http://www.phprs.com.br/2016/05/criando-um-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-php-com-docker-compose/) explica isso. Também tem esse [artigo do mundo docker](https://www.mundodocker.com.br/link-entre-containers/).

Comment: Obrigado @tanya, pela resposta. Eu tentei das duas formas, separados e no mesmo container. Vou ler os artigos que me passou e assim que possível, eu comento aqui o resultado.

Comment: Eu adicionei a propriedade `links` ao docker-compose.yml e depois funcionou, um container não estava "enxergando" o outro.  Vou deixar o docker-compose.yml que utilizei aqui, caso alguém passe por isso com o Firebird.